# When I send 'Public Key' to the other server, There is a backslash which is appended with every backslash already in string

Tags: php, rsa

I send this:

```
'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDER5Frg2/2IsT9U5jfGMZh06Zo\r\nKGJp90d7iXTQf7GKoEIFttn1+hsGm+MtTiZdYnxN5NVPSM5IqDVwC4kg1YX45hTz\r\nGlXEULhoUEIOR1ONDJgAFDZWSC/AoKp2sHHnVMwstmISnOWvTi+aRO2ZUa4ZslJg\r\nPmiffMA0bkG6g8w+3wIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

I received this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\\r\\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDER5Frg2/2IsT9U5jfGMZh06Zo\\r\\nKGJp90d7iXTQf7GKoEIFttn1+hsGm+MtTiZdYnxN5NVPSM5IqDVwC4kg1YX45hTz\\r\\nGlXEULhoUEIOR1ONDJgAFDZWSC/AoKp2sHHnVMwstmISnOWvTi+aRO2ZUa4ZslJg\\r\\nPmiffMA0bkG6g8w+3wIDAQAB\\r\\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

what is the best way to send and receive this?
I am sending it by GET method.(by appending with URL)

Comment: encode/decode base64.

Comment: When you say you received it with the double-backslash, are you sure that's not just a feature of displaying the string? It looks escaped to me

Comment: `urlencode` and `urldecode`? - but surely this will in many cases be longer than the unofficial max length of querystring ( 2048 chars )

Comment: yo! I tried 'stripcslashes($str)' and it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode key using `base64_encode` php function

```
$keyEncoded = base64_encode($key);
```

Then you can send it to via GET request, but its more better if you should send it via POST request

As in GET might be it will overflow query string

Comment: have to mean the only solution. No, you can also encode hex, base91 etc.

Comment: @kelalaka no, but the one solution is above which i describe above